# Simulating TCP/IP Illustrated Test Network

Tags: routing, network, protocol-theory, testing, modem

I just recently bought TCP/IP Illustrated volume 1 first edition for cheap and I see that they reference a test network throughout the book that looks like the following

[image]

Now I'm not the sharpest tool in the shed, but some of these operating systems seem to be quite dated, and I'm unsure if I can even find them to use in virtualbox. Additionally, I've no clue what a Telebit NetBlazer is or what would represent a modem if I attempt to setup a virtual environment to emulate this network.

So my question is, **what would be the easiest way for me to come as close as possible to emulating this test network that the book references so that I can get the most out of the material**?

Comment: Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic for SE sites, except [softwarerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se].

Comment: In Virtualbox, Just use any variety of Linux/Unix for all of the servers and the trailblazer.  Between 'sun' and 'netb' use serial ports with SLIP, ignore the modems.  For 'gateway' use your real Cisco.  You might try it in Cisco's 'packet tracer' simulator if you're more interested in the networking, and can set up modems and dialling; use Virtualbox if you're interested in host configuration details.

Comment: My understanding is question is about simulation, not equipment recommendations.  I've voted to reopen.

Comment: I have a similar question as OP. It doesn’t seem obvious that it violates the rules. Who is eligible to vote to reopen the question?